# Cisco vlan entry missing in vlan.dat, but appears in running-config

Tags: cisco, vlan, configuration, switch

One of our vlan's (ID: 104) stopped working suddenly and computers on that vlan failed when trying to obtain a dhcp ip address.

On the Cisco switch if we do `show vlan`, this command is supposed to shows the vlans in the vlan.dat file. We notice it has every other vlan except the one that is now missing.

If we show the running-config or even the startup config, they DO show the missing vlan (as if everything is fine), but that vlan doesn't take effect.

We tried deleting the "missing" vlan using `clear vlan 104`, but it says `No subinterface configured for vLAN Identifier 104`, so it's already missing. Recreating the vlan, saving and rebooting still doesn't add it into the vlan.dat or make the vlan work.

The switch is in vtp server mode. Our startup config is here: http://pastebin.com/RHxxTG5p

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: In your second paragraph, do you mean the command `show vlan`?

Comment: This is especially odd, as `show run` is a synonym for `show running-config`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant show vlan! Editing...

Comment: What is the actual output of `show vlan`?  You might have the layer 3 interface but not the layer 2 vlan itself.

Comment: Uploaded screenshots of show vlan here. The 104 vlan is missing even though it shows in show run. Screenshot 1 (http://i.imgur.com/ymF5P3j.jpg), Screenshot 2 (http://i.imgur.com/v2QT6N6.png).

Comment: I know these are kind of obvious, but I've seen it happen so many types; - Is the switch out of storage space? It can trigger some very wild erroneous behavior. - Does the entry for the missing VLAN appear in the running-config and/or vlan.dat? On switches, especially if the switch is in VTP transport mode, VLAN entries should appear both in running-config and vlan.dat. If entries in these files do not match, switch goes with the one in vlan.dat.